# Can you help interpret hand-drawn technical drawing?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, technical-drawing

I can't seem to figure out the proper left view for the following image, and the full and half sectional cutout for the left and front projection.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but i have difficulties distinguishing between dashed lines and lines, i cannot read the map.

Comment: Yes the dashed line at end rightmost circle is a bit distracting but i will give a hint there are 2 ramps and a t shaped flat

Comment: I'll make you a 3D model of this later this evening - on mobile now. There is *just* enough information to define the shape, although it's lacking in dimensions... What's this for?

Answer (score 4):

I have made a 3D model of my best guess for this model from your drawing. I've then generated a crib-sheet for the computer generated standard views (first angle projection, as per your sketch), and for some section views. Hopefully one of these provides the information that you're after? - have a look below, and let me know if you have any questions!

[image: Best Guess 3D model]
[image: 2D Drawing Cribsheet]

Comment: Thank you for your consideration and response. Your comments and support really helped to solve my problem. And though some of the lines were unclear, i managed to find a better image @Jonathan R Swift

Comment: I'd love to share it, but I cant seem to find the option for adding pictures in the comment

Comment: Hi - You can upload the image to a sharing site like https://www.imgur.com and then paste a link to the image as a comment?

Comment: Ok. And if you could please take a look at my recent post as well. Thank you.https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/technical-assistance